# Как перехватить клавиатуру при отображаемом JOptionPane?

Tags: java, клавиатура

В моей игре много жмут пробел.
При выполнении условия уровня вызываю `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` с сообщением о завершении уровня.
Соответственно, яростные нажатия на пробел тут же нажимают кнопку `ОК` в сообщении, и оно моментально закрывается.
Хочу создать таймер, который на три секунды будет перехватывать любые нажатия на клавиши и обнулять их.
Не получается перехватить нажатия клавиш. Пробовал:
-создать `MyJOptionPane extends JOptionPane` и вешать на него `KeyListener`. Естественно мимо, потому что фокус на кнопке.
-создать `MyJOptionPane extends JOptionPane` и в нем:

```
@Override
    public Object getInitialValue() {
        return super.getInitialValue(); // удалить строчку
    }
```

-и еще пара способов через `KeyboardFocusManager` и пост-процессинг клавиш.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за ответы.
Я нашел-таки на английском SO ответ в том виде, какой я задумывал.

> It's not a good idea, to do what you want, but I have a solution. You
>   can simply disable all key events when dialog shown. Here is a sample.

```
AWTEventListener myListener = new AWTEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof KeyEvent) {
            ((KeyEvent) event).consume();
        }
    }
};
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(myListener, AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
// <--- здесь я создаю таймер на 3 секунды
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You have a message!");

// <--- следующая строчка помещена в actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) моего таймера.
// + команда stop();
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().removeAWTEventListener(myListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Навешивать обработчик на диалог бесполезно, так как при отображении диалогового окна фокус установлен на кнопку и именно она получает события нажатия пробела. Есть два способа решить эту проблему: Сложный и правильный - это наследовать от `JDialog`, самостоятельно создавать кнопку и навешивать на неё нужные обработчики. А можно решить грязным, но быстрым хаком - сделать пробел клавишей смены фокуса в диалоговом окне, тогда кнопка просто не сможет получить событие нажатия пробела. Правда, создание диалогового окна станет чуть сложнее вызова `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog`:

```
JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("Some text");
JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog("Some dialog");
Set<AWTKeyStroke> focusTraversalKeys = new HashSet<AWTKeyStroke>(dialog.getFocusTraversalKeys(0));
focusTraversalKeys.add(AWTKeyStroke.getAWTKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, KeyEvent.VK_UNDEFINED));
dialog.setFocusTraversalKeys(0, focusTraversalKeys);
dialog.setVisible(true);
dialog.dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вам не подходят стандартные диалоги, то почему бы просто не создать свой?

Ниже пример диалога содержащего надпись "Well done" и кнопку под ним. Кнопка отображает обратный трехсекундный отсчет и не активна до его окончания. По окончанию отсчета кнопка становится активной и надпись сменяется на "ОК".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public class MyDlg extends JDialog implements ActionListener {
        private int seconds = 3;
        private JButton okBtn;
        private Timer timer;
        public MyDlg() {
            setResizable(false);
            setModal(true);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            timer = new Timer(1000, this);
            makeDlg();
            pack();
    }

    private void makeDlg() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.weightx = 1;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Well done!");
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        panel.add(label, constraints);
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        okBtn = new JButton(String.valueOf(seconds));
        okBtn.setEnabled(false);
        okBtn.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(okBtn, constraints);
        add(panel);
    }

    @Override
    public void setVisible(boolean b) {
        timer.start();
        super.setVisible(b);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource().equals(timer)) {
            seconds--;
            if (seconds == 0) {
                timer.stop();
                okBtn.setText("OK");
                okBtn.setEnabled(true);
                okBtn.requestFocus();
            } else
                okBtn.setText(String.valueOf(seconds));
        } else if (e.getSource().equals(okBtn)) {
            this.setVisible(false);
            this.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```